# Catalog search result problem

Tags: magento-1.9, search, catalogsearch

I have a catalog with over 85k articles, when I do a search as a result I always find the usual 4 products. I have also installed the Amasty Search Pro extension and it is able to find all the products in the catalog but only in the popup window.